# Retrieve Authenticate User's Orders

Tags: javascript, object, mongoose

1. GET method
2. Use `accessToken` of an authenticated user.
3. Only non-admin account can proceed.
4. User should be able to retrieve his orders only.

**Router**

````
router.get("/my-orders", auth.verify, (req, res) => {

    const user = auth.decode(req.headers.authorization);

    if (!user.isAdmin) {

        UserController.getMyOrders(req.body).then(getMine => res.send(getMine));


    } else {

        return res.status(403).send("Access denied.");
    }

});```
````

**Controller**

```
module.exports.getMyOrders = (body) => {

    return User.find({}, {
        "isAdmin": 0,
        "_id": 0,
        "password": 0
    });
}
```

I am getting everything. Can someone help me code how to filter the user where the token belongs and retrieve his orders and not able to get other users' orders?

Answer (score 0):

By passing an empty object in your `.find` method, you are telling mongodb to look for everything. I'm assuming in `body` you have some data to find a specific user, if so you would use that. eg. if `body` contains a username, you would write...

```
module.exports.getMyOrders = (body) => {
    return User.find({username: body.username});
}
```

[Here is some more info on db.collection.find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

EDIT - Look up user by JWT:

```
router.get("/my-orders", auth.verify, (req, res) => {
    //Here you have decoded your JWT and saved it as user
    const user = auth.decode(req.headers.authorization);

    if (!user.isAdmin) {
        //here you are passing user instead of req.body
        UserController.getMyOrders(user).then(getMine => res.send(getMine));


    } else {

        return res.status(403).send("Access denied.");
    }

});
```

---

```
module.exports.getMyOrders = (user) => {
    //now you are using 'username' from the decoded jwt to look up the user
    return User.find({username: user.username});
}
```

Comment: How can I declare to find the orders belong to the JWT?

Comment: It looks like you're saving the decoded JWT in the `user` variable, so you would need to pass `user` to your `getMyOrders` function, then use information from your decoded JWT to look up the user. I've added an edit demonstrating this.